# Changing files in glusterfs volume instead of using a client

Tags: glusterfs

I have a volume with replication factor 2 on 2 nodes. So that each brick contains its own copy of all files... Is it possible to avoid using glusterfs client and write/read to/from volume directory directly? It seems to be working exactly as if I mounted it like this: `mount -t glusterfs IP:/mnt/my-volume somewhere`... Whatever I write to the `my-volume` directory on host `A` I can see in the volume directory on host `B`...

Or can DFS be accessed exclusively via the glusterfs client and any other means probably lead to unexpected behavior?